# FacebookWebContext.Current is always null

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

I am trying to edit some code written about two years ago.
Basically, it is Facebook connect, where users can register my website using Facebook application. My javascript code for Facebook connect is :

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>

<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/tr_TR/all.js"></script>
<script>

    FB.init({ appId: '<%=Facebook.FacebookApplication.Current.AppId %>', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });    


    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function (response) {
        window.location.href = UrlAmpReplace('<%=this.FacebookLoginURL %>');
    });

    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function (response) {
        window.location.href = UrlAmpReplace('<%=this.FacebookLogoutURL %>');
    });

</script>
```

If the user clicks the Facebook button,  there a Facebook popup page appears and asks for authenticaion & authorication. After that one, user redirects my own registration page where I use `Facebook.Web.dll` as following :

```
 var fb = new FacebookWebClient(FacebookWebContext.Current);

 var result = (IDictionary<string, object>)fb.Get("/me");

 this.smFacebookUserID = FacebookWebContext.Current.Session.UserId;
```

... do some action..

My problem is;  `FacebookWebContext.Current` always returns null and I cannot process further.Do you have any idea what i am missing?

Comment: It seem that you have the same problem with this fellow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524459/facebookwebcontext-current-isauthenticated-always-returns-false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem, I think the problem is related with the FB js event I was using(auth.login).
So here is what I did :

Instead of the following js method :

```
   FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function (response) {
        window.location.href = UrlAmpReplace('<%=this.FacebookLoginURL %>');
    });
```

I have used the following :

```
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {

       var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
       window.location.href = 'myURL.aspx?token='+accessToken;

    } 
});
```

Then in my `myURL.aspx`, using accessToken from querystring, I can reach :

```
var client = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
```